# is my MYSQL injection statement vulnerable?

Tags: php, mysql

I believe this statement is vulnerable for injection, but am unsure.

Any help in this regard?

Thanks.

```
function CheckUserLogin($userName,$password)
{
    $sql="SELECT user_id 
         FROM users 
         WHERE user_name='".addslashes($userName)."' AND password ='".addslashes($password)."'";    
    $this->query($sql);
    if($this->movenext()>0)
    {
        return $this->col['user_id'];   
    }
    else 
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The query function is as such

```
function query($_query){
    list($usec, $sec) = explode(" ",microtime());
    $time_start  = ((float)$usec + (float)$sec);


    $this->query = $_query;
    $this->result = @mysql_query($_query, $this->link_id) or die("<b>error in sql query</b><br><pre>".$_query."</pre>.mysql error : <b>".mysql_error($this->link_id)."</b><p>");

    list($usec, $sec) = explode(" ",microtime());
    $time_end  =  ((float)$usec + (float)$sec);
    $time = $time_end - $time_start;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what the [docs on `addslashes`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php) say:

> Please note that use of `addslashes()` for database parameter escaping can be cause of security issues on most databases.

The same article has:

> To escape database parameters, DBMS specific escape function (e.g. [`mysqli_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) for MySQL or `pg_escape_literal()`, `pg_escape_string()` for PostgreSQL) should be used for security reasons.

However, the best way to use parameters in SQL statements is by using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). There the parameter values are never injected into the SQL statement, and so there cannot be malicious injection either. Instead the database engine uses the parameter values directly (and as literals) to execute the already compiled query.

Please read [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php): it has lots of information about this subject.

Comment: Thank you, very much appreciate the response.

Answer (score 0):

[Here are some example given about Injection and how to make query injection free.](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)

[And Also Here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet)